# Action in iPhone stopped working!

Tags: iphone, status, mgtwitterengine

i have set up a twitter client on my iphone using mgtwitterengine. i've managed to set it up so i can tweet and recieve status updates.

using the standard set up you can only receive between 10&20 updates. to be able to receive more updates then that you have to put`[_engine getFollowedTimelineSinceID:0 startingAtPage:0 count:50];` but this does not allow you to get more than the original amount untill you activate

```
if (params) {
    fullPath = [self _queryStringWithBase:fullPath parameters:params prefixed:YES];
}
```

in  **SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m.**

my problem is when i do this i can no longer post a new status from my app. i can have upto 200 statuses in the stream but no posting capabilities.
this is the error:Error Domain=HTTP Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)"

any help would be appreciated.

many thanks in advance

SOLVED

i just need to add `if(requestType == MGTwitterUserTimelineRequest || requestType == MGTwitterFollowedTimelineRequest)` before `if (params) {fullPath = [self _queryStringWithBase:fullPath parameters:params prefixed:YES];}`
so that it looks like this:

```
if(requestType == MGTwitterUserTimelineRequest || requestType == MGTwitterFollowedTimelineRequest) {
    if (params) {
        fullPath = [self _queryStringWithBase:fullPath parameters:params prefixed:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your app running into Rate Limiting? How many calls are you making to the Twitter API and to which methods?

Comment: thanks for your reply. i'm not receiving any errors for rate limiting. if i delet the "if params" line i can then post and receive the 15 or so statuses. i only make a call to twitter to update a users status and timeline. exscuse me when i ask this, i'm a bit of a noob, what do you mean by 'methods'?

Comment: [_engine getFollowedTimelineSinceID:0 startingAtPage:0 count:50];

Comment: Please post your "solved" comment as an answer if it fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

i just need to add `if(requestType == MGTwitterUserTimelineRequest || requestType == MGTwitterFollowedTimelineRequest)` before `if (params) {fullPath = [self _queryStringWithBase:fullPath parameters:params prefixed:YES];}`
so that it looks like this:

```
if(requestType == MGTwitterUserTimelineRequest || requestType == MGTwitterFollowedTimelineRequest) {
    if (params) {
        fullPath = [self _queryStringWithBase:fullPath parameters:params prefixed:YES];
    }
}
```